# SQL Server 2005 Replication Stops after a minute without an error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Background:

I have a SQL Server 2005 setup with master, slave1, slave2 replication set up as a pull replication from slaves. The distribution database resides on the slave1 machine, both slaves pull.

A problem began today where the replication on slave1 simply stops running. It claims that it completed successfully, but it does not restart, and manually starting the process finishes in roughly one minute, again without an error message.

[image: Screenshot]

Replication is running fine on slave2, but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong on slave1. I've tried the obvious Windows debugging 101: "restart the machine" technique, but to no avail.

Has anyone encountered this before Does anyone have an idea of what I could check or change to get it working again? I'm especially at a loss as SQL Server claims that the job is just finishing successfully.

Comment: clearly more appropriate at http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I'm unsure of why this began occurring. It appears to be due to the use of a custom SQL Server Replication Agent profile. Switching to using the default got it working again.